# Internal Style Sheet does not apply to h3 heading

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css">
#h1 {
    color: #F60;
}
#h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
</style>
```

My Internal Style sheet applies to all headings of number 1.

But with heading 3, the styles applied in the internal style sheet do not apply to my h3 in my coding.

```
<h3>Internet Addiction</h3>
```

Comment: just use `h3{.....}` not `#h3{........}`

Answer (score 4):

```
   h1 { color:#F60; }  -> <h1>
   .h1 {...}           -> <any-element class="h1"> (btw. using class name/id h1 is confusing)
   #id {...}           -> <any-element id="h1">
```

You use hash (#) with IDs and dot (.) with classes. Remember ID is unique*, while class can be used many times

*Even if you assing the same id to two elements, browsers will apply proper styles, but don't do that.

Comment: Andy, thank you! I'm an amateur! I forgot the rules! 

All sorted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is applied for the `h1`?

You should delete `#`. Your code should be looked like this:

```
h1 {
    color: #F60;
}
h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

Because hash(#) is only used for defining `id`. The `h1` and `h3` are `tag`. 
You can read more details on [w3schools.com/tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp).